# Replace a selected Label with a TextField

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have created `ListView` of `Label`s using :

```
ListView<Label> list = new ListView<Label>();
Image folder = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder.png"));
ObservableList<Label> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();   
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.setText("label" + i);
    lbl.setGraphic(new ImageView(folder));
    lbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT); 
    lbl.setGraphicTextGap(10.2); 
    data.add(lbl);              
}
list.setItems(data);
```

I want the user to be able to double click on any of the `Label`s within the `ListView`, the selected `Label` should be replaced with a `TextField` so that the user can enter a new label name dynamically.

After the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> the `TextField` should turn back into a `Label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Label` as the type of *data* for the `ListView`. Use `String`. Then you can just use the standard [`TextFieldListCell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldListCell.html) which has exactly the functionality you describe. Since you want a graphic in the standard cell display, just subclass `TextFieldListCell` and override the appropriate methods to include the graphic when the text field is not displayed:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class EditableListViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
        Image testImg = new Rectangle(12, 12, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE).snapshot(null, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            list.getItems().add("label "+i);
        }

        StringConverter<String> identityStringConverter = new DefaultStringConverter();

        list.setCellFactory(lv -> new TextFieldListCell<String>(identityStringConverter) {

            private ImageView imageView = new ImageView(testImg);


            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (! empty && ! isEditing()) {
                    setStaticGraphic();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelEdit() {
                super.cancelEdit();
                setStaticGraphic();
            }

            @Override
            public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
                super.commitEdit(newValue);
                setStaticGraphic();
            }

            private void setStaticGraphic() {
                setGraphic(imageView);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
                setGraphicTextGap(10.2);                
            }
        });

        list.setEditable(true);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(list), 250, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use setGraphic  method of label which is not available for Textfield and String Listview ???

Comment: Well, the type of the `ListView` should almost certainly not be a graphical component. It should be some data type that encapsulates the data you need. Then use a `cellFactory` to determine how to display the data in each cell. Perhaps update your question to explain more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: As far as type of `Listview` is concerned its `label` and inside I am using `Label`   `setGraphic` method which is working fine .

I used `cellFactory` but it was replacing whole `Listview` with the new one .

Comment: So, it's working fine, but it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Yes  In short  I want when user click on any `Label` inside my `Listview` selected `Label` replace by `Textfield` I need it for `Listview` of `Label`

Comment: Can you explain why you need a `ListView<Label>`, other than you want a graphic in there (that is not the way to get a graphic into `ListCell`s)? See edited answer for the way I'd do this.

Comment: It what I want .
Unfortunately I can't vote up you because of my reputation.
Thankx